# AIX: Unknown Segmentation fault issue

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, aix

I am having an unknown and abrupt segmentation fault when running my code on AIX. The following line :

```
sourceSample +=value;
```

gives a segmentation fault. Here sourceSample is a pointer which is pointing to an image.

I made some changes to the above line of code and the following happens:

1. `int *p = sourceSample; sourceSample = p + value;`Segmentation fault persists.
2. `int **p = &sourceSample; sourceSample = *p + value;`
   No segmentation fault and the code executes successully.

Can any one tell me why this is happening?

ps: This is my first question of StackOverflow, so pardone me if I missed on anything.

Comment: The thing you missed was posting the entire relevant excerpt from your code, which allows us to reproduce the problem. See also: [MCVE]

Comment: Do you know (a) what the original source line is trying to do, and (b) what those changes you made *actually mean* and how they are different? If not, I'll let you know now: *guessing* is *not* how you learn to program.

Comment: The only way you can ever get a segmentation fault from a C++ program running on a conforming C++ implementation is for that program to exhibit undefined behavior.  We would need a [mcve] to determine the nature of the undefinedness, but a plausible possibility is that `sourceSample + value` would point outside the bounds of the object into which `sourceSample` points.  Attempting to compute such a pointer value is sufficient to produce undefined behavior; you do not, technically, need to dereference the result.

Comment: The entire relevant code excerpt is very large and the point at which memory is getting allocated and where it is getting used is very different. If I try to post a short excerpt from the whole code base then it will make no sense. I understand that without the code excerpt, it is not possible to reproduce the problem, but what I wanted to ask is not why this segmentation fault is occurring, but how my second change is resolving the segmentation fault?

Comment: Could you share the definition of sourceSample itself?

Comment: you should put here, lines of code that used of sourceSample and pointer "p" .

Comment: @VarunKalra *but how my second change is resolving the segmentation fault?* -- Some advice -- if you know that the code you added "solved the problem", and the code itself has nothing to do with the issue, but somehow seemingly, magically "fixes things", that is a clear indication of memory corruption.  I would suggest **removing the line** that magically solves the problem, put the bug back in the program, and really fix the issue.  All you're doing is masking the problem with a do-nothing line of code, and that is no fix.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Thanks for the advice. Will surely consider this and will find out the exact issue. But can you tell me that is there any difference between the lines: 1. sourceSample +=value; and 2. int **p = &sourceSample; sourceSample = *p + value; ? Also this is only happening only on AIX and not on windows or redhat. So might this be issue of assembly generation and I should look into that?

Comment: Use gdb on machine-code debugging level (`stepi`, `diplay/i $pc`, `disass` etc) to find the actual problem.

Comment: If you could compile your code on Linux kernel, you can set below command before execute :


"ulimite -c unlimited"


and run: 


"gdb ./exe_file_name core_file_name"


and file which line of code is your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue to the problem.
The problem is because of the wrong assembly code getting generated in AIX. The segmentation fault is occurring when it tries to access sourceSample after adding 'value' to it using:

```
if(bitPos == bitPos_renew) {
    sourceSample += value;
}
```

When 'value' is added to the sourceSample pointer and sourceSample is tried to access, AIX raises a segmentation fault. This is because of the wrong value in the variable 'value'.

The value of 'value' is assigned using:

```
value = sx <= ex ? 1 : -1;
```

The value assigned to it should be 1 or -1 but when we see at the assembly code the value assigned to 64bit register referring to variable 'value' is

> 00000000FFFFFFFF

and not

> FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF(-1)

Because of this, when 'value' is added to sourceSample, it starts pointing to some unassigned memory causing the segmentation fault.

When I try to print the value of variable 'value', the assembly code gets correct automatically and runs successfully.

This is because of the optimizations of the compiler. If I remove all the optimizations by setting the optimization level to O0, the assembly code is totally fine and there is no segmentation fault.